# undefined method 'connection=' for #IntuitOAuth::Client - QuickBooks oAuth 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online

I am trying to use the QuickBooks API using oAuth 2.0.  My app currently runs perfectly using oAuth 1.0

I am using the quickbooks-ruby gem

```
gem "quickbooks-ruby", '1.0.1'
```

I have successfully migrated a client form oAuth 1.0 to oAuth 2.0 and received the access_token and refresh_token.

Now i'm trying to get the company preferences using oAuth 2.0, and getting an error.
undefined method 'connection=' for #IntuitOAuth::Client:

Please see my code below:

```
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new($oauth2_client, access_token, :refresh_token => refresh_token)

service = Quickbooks::Service::Preferences.new
service.company_id = realm_id
service.access_token = access_token
preferences = service.query("Select * from Preferences")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your code calling `connection = ...` anywhere? the code you show doesn't look like the code the error must by pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The ruby gem i'm using to access the QBO API is incompatible with the intuit-oauth gem that QBO released for the QBO oAuth 2.0 migration.

You have to use one or the other gem.  I have figured out how to get all the oAuth 2.0 operations working without the intuit-oauth gem.